# Adding a <BR /> tag to XML, then displaying via XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm writing a XML file using SimpleXMLElement, and I can't get my br tags to take effect.  The XML the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="scoreboard.xsl"?>
<scoreboard scoreboard_title="Scoreboard for: (lesson) a/an">
    <header>
        <item>User name</item>
        <item>Assessment</item>
    </header>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <item><![CDATA[mega blue]]></item>
            <item><![CDATA[03/03/14: 20% (21.02 sec)<br />07/03/14: 100% (42.56 sec)]]></item>
        </row>
    </rows>
</scoreboard>
```

My XSL file is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="scoreboard">
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="header/item">
                    <th align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">
                <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <td align="left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I get this for my output:

```
User name   Assessment
mega blue   Spanish 03/03/14: 20% (21.02 sec)<br />07/03/14: 100% (42.56 sec)
```

I need the br tag to put the Assessment scores on two lines...

Comment: Have you tried `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in the relevant `<value-of>` tags?

Comment: Adding `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` worked for me. What browser are you rendering the output in? Try loading the XML file fresh to ensure that previous output is not being cached and newly generated output is not being rendered properly. Also, if you can - adjust the XML not to use CDATA, so that you can access and transform the content as you need.

Comment: If I don't use CDATA how do I add <br /> tags to XML - SimpleXMLElement outputs it as &lt;br /&gt; (or something like that...)?

Answer (score 0):

The deep nesting in your stylesheet is very inflexible. Whenever you find yourself writing `xsl:for-each`, consider replacing it with `xsl:apply-templates`, which will save you a lot of headaches now and in the future: template based processing, which is what XSLT is all about, instead of telling the processor how it needs to be done, you just tell the processor what you want to do when it encounters a certain node.

I have rewritten your stylesheet for that matter. Now it more readable and easier to follow. Also, I added the necessary `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to the corresponding `xsl:value-of`. This works in all processors I tried. But in a browser this does not always work, simply because the actual definition of this disable-output-escaping is related to serialization, which is not what a browser does. The only browser that ignores that fact (and actually does what you want) and that interprets the `<br />` as a newline, is Internet Explorer (by getting it wrong, they get it right for you ;).

Here's the stylesheet. Process it serverside so you do not have to deal with browser-quirks and you will get the output you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="scoreboard" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scoreboard">
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="header/item" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rows/row" />

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header/item">
        <th align="left">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rows/row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
        </tr>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <td align="left">
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </td>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will give the following output with your input:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th align="left">User name</th>
               <th align="left">Assessment</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td align="left">mega blue</td>
               <td align="left">03/03/14: 20% (21.02 sec)<br />07/03/14: 100% (42.56 sec)</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, following your last comment under your question, if you can fix it at the source, split the `<td>` in several text nodes, and place a `<br />` in-between. Then, in the matching template, change the `xsl:value-of` into an `xsl:copy-of`, i.e, change the last template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <td align="left">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </td>        
</xsl:template>
```

Note, for this to work, make sure that your input looks as follows:

```
<item>03/03/14: 20% (21.02 sec)<br />07/03/14: 100% (42.56 sec)</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to accomplish this:
1. Tell the transformation engine to output without escaping (disable-output-escaping="yes"). This can break your output because the input won't be parsed and can contain errors.
2. Use an xml element to trigger the break. You can even name it <br />, but it must be in the xml element tree, not inside the CDATA. Be aware that an <br /> tag added into an xml file isn't recognised as a html element. You are free to name your elements as you want and can even use names known from html, but they don't become html automatically. If you want them to be added into the output, you must code that in an template just like you coded an "item" shall exist inside an "td" element.
3. If most of your items contain breaks, maybe even more than one, it can be useful to divide the "item" elements into "line" elements and output them e.g. as "div" or add an "br" in front of every "line" that is not the first (need xpath for this).
4. Use html-style-named elements and copy them into your output (xsl:copy-of, mentioned by Abel). With copying they become part of the output tree being html. Works if you don't mess with namespaces.
Be aware these are different approaches, don't mix them instead you know what you do.